# Spark: How to specify the IP for the driver program to run

Tags: apache-spark, driver

I am having issue to configure specific spark node as driver in my cluster. I am having standalaone mode cluster. Every time on master restart i see that one of the node in the cluster is being randomly picked to run the driver program. Due to which i am enforced to deploy my JAR on all the nodes in my cluster.

If i can specify the IP for the driver program to run, then i need to deploy the JAR only in one node.

Appreciate, any help.

Comment: You should just submit to the master, no? Isn't that the point of fault tolerance? You shouldn't know which node is going to be the driver; the framework is responsible to figure it out

Comment: Does that mean i need to deploy the jar on all the nodes?

Comment: You don't need to no, only the master node (at least that's been my limited experience with spark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run from a particular node you can use:
`--deploy-mode client`
With this option the the driver program will always be running on the machine from where you run spark-submit.

For more information:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit